# Best meaning for "edit link"

Tags: verbs, adjectives

"Edit link" has two possible meanings:

> 1. A link to edit (page)
> 2. To edit the link

How can I know which one is correct? This is part of a translation project and I can't find context of the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context would be the best clarifier, but without that the lack of an article would make me lean towards the second. This is a marginal preference at best, though; without context they're (for the most part) just as likely as each other. Since it's for a translation project, there's probably a coordinator or superior that has access to where the phrase is found, and it probably couldn't hurt to ask.